# ARM NEON my calculation result when there are negative numbers is incorrect

Tags: assembly, arm, neon, alphablending

I am trying to calculate the following using neon in assembly ((200*(53-255))/255) + 255 whose result should equal approx 97

I've tested here http://szeged.github.io/nevada/ and also on a dual-core Cortex-A7 ARM CPU tablet.  And the result is 243 which is not correct.
How should I implement this to get the correct result of 97?

d2 contains 200,200,200,200,200,200,200,200
d4 contains 255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255
d6 contains 53,53,53,53,53,53,53,53

```
vsub.s8 d8, d6, d4  (53 - 255 results in d8 = 54,54,54,54,54,54,54,54)
vmull.s8 q5,d8,d2  (54 * 200 results in q5 = 244,48,244,48,244,48,244,48,244,48,244,48,244,48,244,48)
vshrn.s16 d12, q5, #8 (divide by 255 results in d12 = 244,244,244,244,244,244,244,244) 
vadd.s8 d5, d4, d12  (final result d5 = 243,243,243,243,243,243,243,243)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

243 is absolutely correct.

The alpha channel is an unsigned 8bit value, you should use `u8` or `u16` instead of `s8` and `s16`.

While for standard arithmetics where the bit width remains the same the sign doesn't matter, it's a completely different story for multiply long.

And that's the reason there are two separate instructions for ARM `UMULL` and `SMULL` for long multiply while a single `MUL` instruction will do for 32bit both signed and unsigned multiplications.

54*200 is simply impossible since 200 is interpreted as -56 in a signed multiply.

```
=>
54*-56 = -3024
-3024/256 = -12
-12 + -1 = -13    // 255 = -1
-13 = 243
```

You actually have to change `vmull.s8` to `vmull.u8` :

```
=>
54*200 = 4800
2800/256 = 18
18 + -1 = 17
```

Honestly, I don't know how you are expecting a result of 97 with the ops above : how is it supposed to be some kind of alpha blending as one of the tags is implying?

Further, `>>8` is NOT `/255`. It's just a bad approximation. You might think you can live with a precision that low, but it's FAR from sufficient when alpha blending.

You must be doing something wrong.

Comment: the alpha blending formula I'm trying to implement in neon asm is output_red = ((alpha_front * (red_front - red_bak))/255) + red_bak and repeat for the blue and green pixels. I am expecting a result of 97 when red_front = 53, red_bak = 255, and alpha_front = 200.  via a calculator: 53 - 255 = -202, -202 x 200 = -40,400, -40,400/255 = -158 and finally -158 + 255 = 97.  I've already tried vmull.u8 and then the result is 41. With regards to the shift right or divide by 255, there are some references for using it here http://www.gamedev.net/topic/34688-alpha-blend-formula/

Comment: That's wrong. The correct formula is : rslt = (alpha*front + (255-alpha)*back)/255.

Comment: (200*53+55*255)/255 = 96. The correct result for the given values is 96, 97 with rounding

Comment: Thanks, and I understand from my research that there are a number of different formulas for alpha blending.  I actually implemented the formula ((alpha*(front-back))/255)+back that I listed out in my question in python and it works very well @Jake.  I wish I could send you the screenshot of how it looks because it looks very very good. However the implementation is very slow because it is implemented in python.  I am trying to now implement this in neon asm.

Comment: The formula you are using ignores two things : 1) It tries to reduce multiply in the hope of being faster. But modern CUPs like ARM nowdays have very fast multiply-accumulate instructions. Therefore, it does exactly the opposite. 2) It requires the full bit-width of register. It's simply not appropriate for SIMD, where saving bits increases performance massively. => You should use the formula I gave for NEON.

Comment: thanks.  I just tested out your formula in python and looks good.  I am now porting this over to asm neon and will update shortly #Jakes alpha blend formula rslt = (alpha*front + (255-alpha)*back)/255 
        output_red = (alpha_front * red_front + (255-alpha_front) *red_bak)/255 
        output_green = (alpha_front * green_front + (255-alpha_front) *green_bak)/255
        output_blue = (alpha_front * blue_front + (255-alpha_front) *blue_bak)/255

Comment: brilliant @Jake!! Thanks for the tips and pointers, its working great now -cheers   vmull.u8 q5,d6,d2
vsub.u8 d8, d4, d2
vmull.u8 q6,d8,d4
vadd.u8 q6,q6,q5
vshrn.u16 d14, q6, #8